# Efficient way to check if Object contain any field with null/empty value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I think we all have faced this check, do any field value is blank or not?
I did it like this(in lightning)

```
var commonObj = component.get('v.commonObj');
    if(  $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.FirstName)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.LastName)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.FatherName)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.Gender)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.Mobile)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.City)
              || $A.util.isEmpty(commonObj.State)){
                 alert('Please fill the missing values.');
}
```

I feel it's the poorest way of doing this as

- What if the number of fields is large(say 60-80)

But, before writing the above code I tried to use reduce method as

```
var commonObj = component.get('commonObj');    
var validInput = commonObj.reduce(function (validSoFar, fieldVal) {
                return validSoFar && $A.util.isEmpty(fieldVal);
            }, true);
            if(validInput){  
    }
```

But this code says

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [commonObj.reduce is not a
>   function]

I'm looking for some efficient way of doing the same. Also, 1 more thing, why reduce method is not a function error is occurring? I tried using reduce method many times to do client-side validation of data entered as

```
var isAllValid = component.find('myform').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
        }, true);
        if(isAllValid){}
```

But every time it gave me the same error

> reduce is not a
>   function

Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing mistake with reduce method syntax. Yoiu need to find attribute and then need to validate value while currently it looks like you are fetching object and then doing validation.

```
<lightning:input aura:id="fieldId" required="true" label="Name" name="filename" value="{!v.Name}"/>
```

and then in controller

```
var allValid = component.find('fieldId').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
     inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
     return validSoFar && !inputCmp.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
}, true);
if (allValid) {
    alert('All form entries look valid. Ready to submit!');
} else {
    alert('Please update the invalid form entries and try again.');
}
```

Comment: I'm new to js and have a question is it necessary to use component.find with reduce method? What I think it needs an array/list to iterate. Like I found a code something like  `var total = [0, 1, 2, 3].reduce(function(sum, value) {
  return sum + value;
}, 0);
// total is 6`

Comment: @VDahiya yes array will work as well.

Comment: And I guess we should use `inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid` insead of `inputCmp.get('v.validity').valueMissing` because `valueMissing` will return true only if value is missing and doesn't reports for other validity attribute properties like: badInput.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma my main issue was to ask the efficient way to check if an object contains a field with the null value. As per you, we can not use reduce method with an object to check this validation. Then what can we do to make it like an efficient code not just  a code with lot of  of if condisions?

Comment: @VDahiya instead of object you need to pass array of all fields. They can be related to same object. Its just you are referring wrong attribute.